# how can I get the first unique ID element and last unique ID element in an array React js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

i have a data this data https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-26pgys
how can i filter the json that i can get the first unique ID and last Unique ID

i have tried filtering the data like this

```
let pp = this.state.data.filter(
            (ele, ind) => ind === this.state.data.findIndex(elem => elem.id === ele.id))
```

which filter all unique ids.

i would like the data result to be something like this

```
[{"id":"9000108","date":"2019-07-25","time":"17:49:23"},{"id":"9000108","date":"2019-07-25","time":"18:06:16"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:32:12"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-31","time":"20:13:15"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:25:10"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"13:11:14"}, ....etc.]
```

Comment: But your result data example doesn't have unique id?

Comment: So since this question deals with time related data. Then for each id, you want the objects of the first item logged and the last item logged correct?

Comment: When you say 'unique' id, do you mean id's that only occur once?

Comment: @rrd yes that is what i ment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is already organized chronologically, you could use `array.reduce()` to shape your data. Then use `Object.values()` and `array.flatMap()` to create your unique array.

```
let dict = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if(!obj[item.id]){
        obj[item.id] = []
    }

    obj[item.id].push(item)

    return obj
}, {})

let unique = Object.values(dict).flatMap((arr) => {
    return [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]]
})
```

The result is an array with 32 items. 2 for each unique ID.

Comment: wow bro thankyou verry much!! i would not have think this in a million years! haha

Comment: @user3121362 you're welcome bro! This was a fun question, and I think you'll be able to solve stuff like this yourself very soon :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you formulated your question a bit wrong? Probably, you meant this thing - "How to get a first and last records with the same id in array?". If I am right, this question doesn't belong to React, but to Native JavaScript. Here is an answer:

```
const formatted = this.state.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // Check if there are no items with this ID in accumulator still
    if (!acc.some(r => r.id === item.id)) {
        // Find all records with same ID
        const withSameId = records.filter(r => r.id === item.id);
        acc.push(withSameId[0]);

        if (withSameId.length > 1) {
            acc.push(withSameId[withSameId.length - 1]);
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

You could optimize this script using something like cache (instead of using `acc.some` we could use hashmap where key is id to make this check rather faster).

Comment: yeah your question is right! and the your answer is splendid! thank you very much

Comment: btw the `records` would be the same as `this.state.data`

Answer (score 1):

If your data is sorted you can `reduce` with a single iteration by keeping a reference on the previous id.

```js
const data = [{"id":"9000108","date":"2019-07-25","time":"17:49:23"},{"id":"9000108","date":"2019-07-25","time":"18:06:16"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:32:12"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:32:15"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:32:18"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"16:26:24"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"20:09:53"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"20:09:56"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"20:10:07"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-25","time":"20:13:49"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-26","time":"06:40:48"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-26","time":"06:40:51"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-26","time":"10:31:31"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-31","time":"20:13:08"},{"id":"14947","date":"2019-07-31","time":"20:13:15"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:25:10"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"07:25:12"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"08:38:56"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"08:51:54"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-25","time":"09:29:29"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"13:01:36"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"13:09:02"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"13:19:58"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"13:20:55"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"14:14:09"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"14:18:46"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"16:16:47"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"16:19:42"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"16:21:39"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"16:47:15"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"16:53:48"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"17:45:57"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"17:48:55"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"17:53:56"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"17:56:03"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"17:58:37"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"20:13:29"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-30","time":"20:13:45"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"07:33:59"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"07:34:01"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"07:53:13"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"09:01:26"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"10:12:33"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:22:43"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:23:03"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:24:15"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:28:30"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:42:59"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"11:54:20"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"13:10:53"},{"id":"9000110","date":"2019-07-31","time":"13:11:14"}];

let previousId = data[0].id;
const result = data.reduce((acc, e, i) => {
  if(previousId !== e.id) {
    acc.push(data[i - 1], e);
    previousId = e.id;
  }
  return acc;
}, [data[0]]);

// add the last item
result.push(data[data.length - 1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: loved it!! it gets the job done and much more cleaner thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have lodash you can use [findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findIndex) and [findLastIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findLastIndex)

```
const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': true }
];

_.findIndex(users, function(o) { return o.active; });
// => 0
_.findLastIndex(users, function(o) { return o.active; });
// => 2
```